# CakePHP hasOne/belongsTo model relationship

Tags: cakephp, orm, relationship, belongs-to, has-one

I have a few models I'm trying to relate.

One model is `Item`, one is `Slide`, and another is `Asset`.

Items have multiple slides beneath them.  Assets are basically files that have been uploaded (images, mp3s, etc) and slides are where assets are displayed.  Each slide has one asset, but a given asset might belong to multiple slides.  A slide has an `asset_id` field defined.

I currently have the models defined as:

**Slide**

```
class Slide extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Slide';

    var $order = array("Slide.order" => "asc");

    var $belongsTo = 'Item';

    var $hasOne = array(
        'Asset' => array(
          'className' => 'Asset',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );

} // Slide class
```

**Asset**

```
class Asset extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Asset';

    var $displayField = 'name';

    var $belongsTo= array(
        'Assetdir' => array(
            'className' => 'Assetdir',
            'foreignKey' => 'assetdir_id'
        ),
        'Slide' => array(
            'className' => 'Slide',
            'foreignKey' => 'id'
        )
    );  
} // Asset class
```

When I load a slide, I'm seeing its parent element, Item, come through in the returned data, but the associated asset is not.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think this is a one-to-many relationship between Slide and Asset. From the [Model associations page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html): *belongsTo: the current model contains the foreign key.* So, any model that has a foreign key to another one **belongs to** the other one.

So the way I see it:

Item:

- hasMany Slide

Slide:

- belongsTo Item (with item_id)
- belongsTo Asset (with asset_id)

Asset:

- hasMany Slide

For retrieving the associated models you want, I'd suggest looking at the [Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I'd been coming at this from the wrong direction.  I guess then I'm wondering, what would be a relationship where hasOne would be appropriate?

Comment: hasOne is frequently for breaking up data into multiple tables.  For example, a User has one Profile.  The data could all be placed on the User model, but breaking it up allows you to make functionality more granular.

Comment: **hasOne** is better suited to one-to-one relationships. The example they give on that associations page is a User and their Profile. A User hasOne Profile, and the Profile belongsTo User (because it has the foreign key *user_id*).