# CakePHP - Related values not showing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm busy with an invoice project in CakePHP. I've set my related tables in the models, but somehow it's not forwarding to the view.

These are my models:

Invoice Model

```
class Invoice extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne  = array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'className'    => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey'   => 'id'
        ),
        'Project' => array(
            'className'    => 'Project',
            'foreignKey'   => 'id'
        ),      
    );

    ...
```

Project Model

```
class Project extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne  = array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'className'    => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey'   => 'id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(    
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className'    => 'Invoice',
            'foreignKey'   => 'project_id'
        ),
    );
```

Customer Model

```
class Customer extends AppModel {

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'full_name' => 'CONCAT(Customer.frontname, " ", Customer.lastname)',
        'display_name' => 'IF(Customer.company > " ", Customer.company, CONCAT(Customer.frontname, " ", Customer.lastname))',
    );

    public $hasMany = array(        
        'Project' => array(
            'className' => 'Project',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        ),
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        ),
    );
```

And the view:

```
<?php
foreach($invoices as $invoice){
?>

        <td><?php echo $invoice['Customer']['display_name']; ?></td>    
        <td><?php echo $invoice['Project']['project_name']; ?></td>
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class InvoicesController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Status');

    public function index() {
        $uid = $this->Auth->user('cloud_id');
        $this->set('uid', $uid);

        $allInvoices = $this->Invoice->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                    'Invoice.cloud_id' => $this->Auth->user('cloud_id'),
                )
            )
        );

        $this->set('invoices', $allInvoices);
    }
```

If I print an Invoice, I can see the related fields, but the values are empty. Like so:

```
Array
(
    [Invoice] => Array
        (
            [id] => 143
            [cloud_id] => 1
            [invoice_number] => 143
            [customer_id] => 2
            [date] => 2013-08-17
            [period] => 30
            [project_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [notes] => 
            [secret] => df56cd45ea7cb086458cc5c3480f77c386647a86
        )

    [Customer] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [cloud_id] => 
            [company] => 
            [frontname] => 
            [lastname] => 
            [address] =>
```

But if I change the foreign keys in the models, I get an error that the column doesn't exists.

What is going wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is controller ?

Comment: Those relationships are wrong. Try linking your models with **conditions** and setting `foreignKey` to false instead. What version of Cake are you using? Older versions are horrible for linking models unless you specifically use their recommended DB schemas (for foreign key names)

Comment: I've added the controller.

I'm using 2.4.3.

Comment: See this answer on similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20462719/2812842

Comment: Why dont you check the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `HasOne` association try to use `BelongsTo`,

```
class Invoice extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo  = array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'className'    => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey'   => 'customer_id'
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind your tables as you are doing in the above code! These relationships are not correct and could be difficult to understand.

Here is one solution

Step 1: create one function in Invoice model, lets say getData()

Step 2: inside that function write below code with small edits like in fields array...

```
$options = array(
            'conditions' => array('Invoice.cloud_id' => $this->Auth->user('cloud_id')),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'alias' => 'Customer',  
                    'table' => 'customers',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Customer.id = Invoice.id',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'alias' => 'Project',  
                    'table' => 'projects',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Project.id = Invoice.id',
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'fields' => array('PUT DESIRED FIELDS COMMA SEPERATED')
        );
   $returnData = $this->find('all',$options);
```

Step 3: execute your code, it will result data.

Hope it will solve your problem.